# Is it acceptable to use an enum to specify class subtype?

Tags: java, oop

Is it acceptable in java to use an enum field to specify class subtype?
In my case there are not many types (less than 20).
Or is it better to use inheritance or inner class?

**target class:**

```
package example;

public class Event{
    private EventType eventType;
    //...
}
```

**enum with subtypes:**

```
package example;

public enum EventType{
    TYPE_1,
    TYPE_2,
    TYPE_3,
    //...
    TYPE_N
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea. The main problem when using enums this way is that you start putting switch statements all over your code - which leads to maintenance nightmares quickly. You should rather looking into ways to use inheritance/polymorphism.

Comment: This is not a good idea, but you should add more details so we can point a better, specific way to go.

Comment: Please read my analytical answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48094368/6390798)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better generally to use polymorphism from an OOP of view to add different behaviors to the Events. So creating multiple Event classes is better. Using an enum, you will eventually use switch and if/else statements every time you want to add special cases, so the code will become less maintainable, like below:

```
public void doSomething() {

    if(eventType == EVENT_1) {
         ....
    } else if (eventType == EVENT_2) {
         ....
    }
}
```

Another solution is to create enums but with behavior like below:

```
public enum EventType {
     FREE_EVENT,  // Use default implementations for methods
     CHARITY_EVENT {
          public void isFree() {
              return false;
          }
          public int cost() {
              return 1000;
          }
     };

     public boolean isFree() {
         return true;
     }

     public int cost() {
         return 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: @Kayaman I usually like the interface approach for both reasons: no *abstract* methods in the `enum` definition and it  enamples mocking to test the code using the enums...

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit. I also semantically switched the meaning of "event". @TimothyTruckle indeed you could stick an interface in there, but I wouldn't consider the lack of abstract methods a problem, and mocking could still be done with the right tools. But there all kinds of possibilities.

Comment: Yes, no problem for the edit. Now it seems better with meaningful methods!

Comment: @Kayaman *"mocking could still be done with the right tools"* I personally see *PowerMock* as a surrender to bad design. Using it on *enums* might be a valid exception, but if you have it in your project its hard to ignore (for the team members of cause...)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle True true, I'd say the chosen approach is highly dependent on the type and amount of behaviour in the enums.